# Operation Time Out

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config

I have a `windows application using wcf services.` As per functionality wise the code is working properly. Well i just wanted to debug some code so i inserted Some `break points` in one of by class file. SO when i was debugging the code i was regularly getting an exception`Operation Timed out.` SO in my Web.config i checked the`execution time` it was `2400`. So i guess execution time is not an issue. If i run the code without debugging it works fine. What may be the issue then?

```
sendTimeout="10:15:00"
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="2400" maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
```

Comment: did you check the sendTimeout for the basicHttpBinding? please add some code to your question

Comment: @TechieBee Please check it now

Comment: executionTimeOut is only considered when debug attribute in the compilation element is false.Can you check this & revert.